# How to use $set + $setOnInsert inside findOneAndUpdate() together with aggregation pipeline operators in MongoDB via mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How to use $set + $setOnInsert inside findOneAndUpdate() together with aggregation pipeline operators in MongoDB via mongoose?

I have code that looks like below:

```
      const newUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        findOneAndUpdateQuery,
        [
          {
            $set: {
              registeredAt: {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $not: ["$registeredAt"],
                  },
                  new Date(),
                  "$registeredAt",
                ],
              },
              createdAt:{
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $not: ["$createdAt"],
                  },
                  new Date(),
                  "$createdAt",
                ],
              },
          },
          // {$setOnInsert: {
          //   registeredAt: new Date(),
          // }},
        ],
        {
          new: true,
          runValidators: true,
          upsert: true,
          setDefaultsOnInsert: true,
        }
      );
```

My user model looks like:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    registeredAt: Date,
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
      required: true,
    },
  },
);
```

If I do not put the `createdAt` field in the set pipeline it is not set when the document is upserted.

Why do I need a `registeredAt` field? Because a user can be present but not registered. Also in this particular query the user does get registered but the query is also called after the user is registered too. So I need for the query not to update the `createdAt` and `registeredAt` fields in subsequent queries.

Is it possible to use `$setOnInsert` with the query above to achieve my goal? Also why aren't the defaults set when I use the aggregation pipeline operators with `$set`?